# Unable to open most shape files from naturalearthdata with geotools: Invalid empty measure

Tags: java, swing, gis, shapefile, geotools

Found that I am unable to open most [shape files from NaturalEarthData](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/50m/cultural/50m_cultural.zip) with GeoTools 11.0.

I am running tutorial ["Maven Quickstart"](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/maven.html) which loads given shape file and shows it. Error occurs inside swing frame, opened with

```
JMapFrame.showMap(map)
```

line.

The error is follows:

```
SEVERE: Invalid empty measure '', was expecting a number, eventually followed by px, m or ft
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid empty measure '', was expecting a number, eventually followed by px, m or ft
    at org.geotools.styling.visitor.Measure.processLiteralExpression(Measure.java:97)
    at org.geotools.styling.visitor.Measure.<init>(Measure.java:63)
    at org.geotools.styling.visitor.UomRescaleStyleVisitor.rescale(UomRescaleStyleVisitor.java:92)
    at org.geotools.styling.visitor.UomRescaleStyleVisitor.rescale(UomRescaleStyleVisitor.java:170)
    at org.geotools.styling.visitor.UomRescaleStyleVisitor.rescaleFill(UomRescaleStyleVisitor.java:211)
    at org.geotools.styling.visitor.UomRescaleStyleVisitor.visit(UomRescaleStyleVisitor.java:204)
    at org.geotools.styling.PolygonSymbolizerImpl.accept(PolygonSymbolizerImpl.java:140)
    at org.geotools.styling.visitor.DuplicatingStyleVisitor.copy(DuplicatingStyleVisitor.java:471)
    at org.geotools.styling.visitor.DuplicatingStyleVisitor.visit(DuplicatingStyleVisitor.java:278)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.rescaleFeatureTypeStyle(StreamingRenderer.java:2464)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.applyUnitRescale(StreamingRenderer.java:2325)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processStylers(StreamingRenderer.java:2011)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.paint(StreamingRenderer.java:837)
    at org.geotools.swing.RenderingTask.call(RenderingTask.java:106)
    at org.geotools.swing.RenderingTask.call(RenderingTask.java:41)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same exception today and got rid of it by using

```
Style style = SLD.createPolygonStyle(....)
```

instead of

```
Style style = SLD.createSimpleStyle(featureSource.getSchema());
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this line:

```
Style style = SLD.createSimpleStyle(featureSource.getSchema());
```

for this:

```
Style style = SLD.createSimpleStyle(featureSource.getSchema(), Color.GRAY);
```

it works for me.

p.d.: Hopefully you will excuse my level of English.